# Building libjpeg-turbo with conan fails on windows

Tags: conan, libjpeg-turbo

I am trying to build `libjpeg-turbo` package with conan on Windows:

```
conan install libjpeg-turbo/1.5.2@bincrafters/stable
```

But it fails with:

```
libjpeg-turbo/1.5.2@bincrafters/stable: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
libjpeg-turbo/1.5.2@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'conan-center'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt
Downloading conanfile.py
Downloading conan_export.tgz
....
ERROR: libjpeg-turbo/1.5.2@bincrafters/stable: Error in configure() method, line 43
    if self.settings.os == "Emscripten":
    ConanException: Invalid setting 'Emscripten' is not a valid 'settings.os' value.
Possible values are ['Android', 'Arduino', 'FreeBSD', 'Linux', 'Macos', 'SunOS', 'Windows', 'WindowsStore', 'iOS', 'tvOS', 'watchOS']
Read "http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/faq/troubleshooting.html#error-invalid-setting"
```

The same command on Linux works fine.
On both system I have conan in version 1.21.0

I cannot find any clue about this error.

**EDIT**

Here is full output of libjpeg-turbo in version 2.0.2 installation:

```
>conan install -r conan-center libjpeg-turbo/2.0.2@
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86
arch_build=x86
build_type=Release
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.runtime=MD
compiler.version=15
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

ERROR: libjpeg-turbo/2.0.2: Error in configure() method, line 49
        if self.settings.os == "Emscripten":
        ConanException: Invalid setting 'Emscripten' is not a valid 'settings.os
' value.
Possible values are ['Android', 'Arduino', 'FreeBSD', 'Linux', 'Macos', 'SunOS',
 'Windows', 'WindowsStore', 'iOS', 'tvOS', 'watchOS']
Read "http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/faq/troubleshooting.html#error-invalid-sett
ing"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conan package libjpeg-turbo/1.5.2@bincrafters/stable is obsolete and has been replaced by libjpeg-turbo/2.0.2@. You can obtain that package from Conan Center as well:

```
conan install -r conan-center libjpeg-turbo/2.0.2@
```

Now about your error:

> ConanException: Invalid setting 'Emscripten' is not a valid 'settings.os' value.

As you can see, your current **settings.os** is configured as `Emscripten` which is not supported by that recipe. As the FAQ link indicates, you should customize your current settings, thus you can try:

```
conan install -r conan-center libjpeg-turbo/2.0.2@ -s os=Windows
```

Thus, you should:

- Update your current package to libjpeg-turbo/2.0.2@ (it requires Conan >=1.18)
- Update your current profile to Windows:

  ```
  conan profile update settings.os=Windows default
  ```

If you really need `Emscripten`, so open an issue to [Conan Center Index](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues) requesting such feature.

Regards!

Comment: I ran `conan install -r conan-center libjpeg-turbo/2.0.2@ -s os=Windows` and exactly the same happend. And I do not need Emscripten for this build.

Comment: Could you please provide a link with your log? Actually there is no detail about your profile and settings. It should be similar to https://gist.github.com/uilianries/a170d428d20b1e547f3b2dad07a60a32

Comment: I see now, you settings file looks outdated. Remove it, Conan will generate a new one. `rm ~/.conan/settings.yml`

Comment: It helped. Could you please tell me how did you notice my config was outdated? If I run conan now, configuration it reports looks the same.

Comment: Emscripten is a new OS supported in settings. When you update your Conan version, it does not replace your current settings.yml, only creates a new version. Thus is was complaining about an absent OS which should be present in your settings.yml. It's not a new "error", actually even I saw similar problem on Linux.